# The airlines changed the flight date, do I have the right to ask them to pay for the hotel?

Tags: air-travel, emirates

I've booked a flight from Glasgow to Basrah on the 4th of June. Leg1 arrives at Dubai at 7:55 on the 5th of June, leg2 departures at 13:55 from Dubai on the same date so that's less than 6 hours to wait at the airport.

Emirates airlines left me a voicemail yesterday asking me to contact them as leg2 flight has been shifted by a whole 24hours to depart at 13:55 on the 6th of June.

I haven't called them yet to discuss my options but the ideal solution for me would be to spend the 24 hours at a hotel inside the airport as I am not interested in visiting Dubai or getting a transit Visa. Do I have the right to ask to pay for the hotel?

**Update:** Will I need a Visa? I am a British citizen

Comment: You do have the right to ask anything although it doesn't necessarily mean they will cough up the funds. Per the EU rules however, you have a case. http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm

Comment: As a British citizen you do not need a visa.  You technically receive a (free) 30-day visitors visa upon arrival - just a stamp in your passport.

Comment: If you have a full day, and you're not jetlagged, deciding to go out and about keep in mind that it is Ramadan.  Check with restaurants and hotel bars whether they are serving behind curtains to non-Muslims during the day.  Grocery stores will be open, however, do not consume food or beverages in public out of courtesy.

Answer (score 21):

Since you are travelling from the EU and your flight departs in less than 14 days, you should be eligible for [EU261](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation_261/2004) compensation regarding the delay, or effective cancellation of the second leg of your flight. This should be 600 Euro and would be sufficient to pay for your additional night's accommodation.

Alternatively you may seek an alternative EU261 mandated option such as a refund or *re-routing to the same destination at the earliest opportunity (under comparable conditions)*.

Since Emirates does provide certain passengers with STPC (stopover paid by carrier), they may be amenable to extending this accommodation to you even though it appears that you aren't technically eligible according to Emirates' [rules](https://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/dubai-connect/dubai-connect.aspx) as it's only eligible for passengers transiting for less than 24 hours upon arrival in Dubai.

Note that normally airlines are not liable for consequential losses with regards to schedule changes. For consequential losses it would be typical for airlines to advise you that you should seek compensation from your travel insurance if you have it.

UK Citizens can get a [visa on arrival](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/united-arab-emirates/entry-requirements) in Dubai if you wish to exit the airport.

ps. it might be advisable to politely ask for the STPC accommodation first and then seek EU261 compensation later ;)

Comment: Would EU rules apply to a flight departing DXB?  Seems that's OP's issue.

Comment: @Johns-305 The OP is departing Glasgow.

Comment: It's Leg2 ex DXB that's changed according to OP's scenario. No mention of the GLA flight being changed.

Comment: @Johns-305 It doesn't matter. It's the origin and destination that matters and now the OP will be arriving late therefore it's subject to EU261

Comment: Well, that's not what OP is describing: "*leg2 flight has been shifted by a whole 24hours*".  Leg 2 departs DXB.  No mention of the GLA flight change at all, meaning, it's not arriving late.

Comment: @Johns-305 Of course it's arriving late. He was just to arrive 24 hours earlier than he is now.

Comment: Um...no, that's *not* what OP is describing.  I quoted exactly the situation as described.  EK is only changing the DXB-BSR flight.  This is no indication at all that GLA-DXB has changed in any way.  How would EU rules apply to a flight that is departing from DXB?  That's the question.

Comment: @Johns-305 if the whole flight was bought from one source then it doesn't matter that the second leg is fully outside of the EU, as the compensation is around your whole flight, not based on the particular legs of your flight. However if the two tickets were bought separately then it's a different problem

Comment: His original plan involved 6 hours stopover.  EK's revision, **at EK's discretion**, gives him 30 hours stopover.  EK's rules say STPC may be offered in other circumstances, and this would certainly seem to qualify.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm I'd tend to agree that there's a good chance